# Chrome driver Session not created - selenium web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm doing some web scraping on a js rendered website using python. Here is my code:

```
import selenium
url2 = 'https://www.adviserratings.com.au/find-an-adviser/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url2)
```

I've done a lot of research, and most of the similar problems are caused by Chrome diver version or Chrome version.

I'm pretty sure my chrome driver and chrome version are correct. But it still shows the error message as below:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 
(68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 
x86_64)
```

It will launch a chrome but unable to open anything, after a few seconds, it will be closed and pop up with error message

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc9Go.png)

Anyone can help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try another url

Answer (score 0):

The script below works perfectly fine for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

url = 'https://www.nissanusa.com/dealer-locator.html'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # wait page open complete

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'dealers-view'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
```

You know you have to put in the path to the chromedriver.exe, right.  Finally, the URL that you posted doesn't really have a lot of material worthy of screen scraping.  Usually people try to get lists, or data from tables, or some such thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the path to chromedriver, but it still doesn't work. I also tried your code, it pop up with same error. I've attached the screenshot in the question description.

Comment: Hummm, I just viewed your screen shot.  I'm not sure what's going on.  Come configuration setting must have gotten mangled, I guess.   It's just a guess.  What works for me should work for you, and everyone else using the same application(s).  There is something wrong on your end.  Maybe you can do a little troubleshooting and post back here, or start a new discussion.  Good luck!!